# The Android program does not execute getView function inside BaseAdapter Class

Tags: java, android, baseadapter

This is a simple program which uses custom layout by using BaseAdapter. The Logcat shows that all other functions have been executed, except for the getView function. On Running the App, I just receive a blank screen.

Here is the code in MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public final String TAG = "Task:";

    //Objects for the arraylist is created from this class.
    public class codeLearnChapter {

        String chapterName;
        String chapterDescription;
    }

    //Defined Custome Adapter.
    MyAdapter mMyAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_simple_list);
        Log.i(TAG, "listview is set as contentview");

        //Initialized custom adapter.
        mMyAdapter = new MyAdapter();
        Log.i(TAG,"New adapter mMyAdapter created");

        ListView codeLearnLessons = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listId);
        Log.i(TAG,"ListView is inflated");

        codeLearnLessons.setAdapter(mMyAdapter);
        Log.i(TAG, "mMyAdapter is set to ListView codeLearnLessons");
    }

    public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        //Data for the arraylist codeLearnChapterList is obtained from getDataForListView() method.
        List<codeLearnChapter> codeLearnChapterList = getDataForListView();

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            Log.i(TAG, "Arraylist size is sent");
            return codeLearnChapterList.size();

        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Object of particular row is sent");
            return codeLearnChapterList.get(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {

            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

            if(arg1==null){

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                arg1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, arg2, false);
                Log.i(TAG, "row of listitem is inflater");
            }

            TextView mChapterName = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            Log.i(TAG,"main description is referenced to its value");

            TextView mChapterDescription = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            Log.i(TAG, "sub description is referenced to its value");

            codeLearnChapter mcodeLearnChapter = codeLearnChapterList.get(arg0);
            Log.i(TAG, "particular of object corresponding to row arg0 is passed to object mcodeLearnChapter");

            mChapterName.setText(mcodeLearnChapter.chapterName);
            Log.i(TAG, "chapterName is Set");

            mChapterDescription.setText(mcodeLearnChapter.chapterDescription);
            Log.i(TAG,"chapterDescription is Set");

            return arg1;
        } 

    }

    public List<codeLearnChapter> getDataForListView(){

        List<codeLearnChapter> codeLearnChapterList = new ArrayList<codeLearnChapter>();

        //The arraylist codeLearnChapterList is populated with 3 objects.
        for(int i=10;i<3;i++){

            codeLearnChapter mcodeLearnChapter = new codeLearnChapter();            
            mcodeLearnChapter.chapterName = "Chapter"+ i;
            mcodeLearnChapter.chapterDescription = "Description for Chapter"+i;

            codeLearnChapterList.add(mcodeLearnChapter);
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "Data (List of objects ) populated in arraylist ");
        return codeLearnChapterList;

    }

}
```

And here's the logcat output

```
06-26 01:41:15.815: I/Task:(1403): listview is set as contentview
06-26 01:41:15.825: I/Task:(1403): Data (List of objects ) populated in arraylist 
06-26 01:41:15.825: I/Task:(1403): New adapter mMyAdapter created
06-26 01:41:15.835: I/Task:(1403): ListView is inflated
06-26 01:41:15.835: I/Task:(1403): Arraylist size is sent
06-26 01:41:15.845: I/Task:(1403): Arraylist size is sent
06-26 01:41:15.845: I/Task:(1403): Arraylist size is sent
06-26 01:41:15.845: I/Task:(1403): mMyAdapter is set to ListView codeLearnLessons
06-26 01:41:16.055: I/Task:(1403): Arraylist size is sent
06-26 01:41:16.055: I/Task:(1403): Arraylist size is sent
06-26 01:41:16.705: I/Task:(1403): Arraylist size is sent
06-26 01:41:16.705: I/Task:(1403): Arraylist size is sent
```

I'm not sure if this is a Java or Android issue since I'm relatively new to programing. It will be really helpful to get clarification as I've been re reading the code for past couple of days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

```
for(int i=10;i<3;i++){
```

Your `ArrayList` is not filled with object thus the `getView` is not called because it is empty.

What you did in the above code is that you are initializing your **i** to 10 which would end the **forloop** immediately.

**solution:**

change it to zero if you want to fill your array with 3 object.

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
```

Comment: This is so embarrassing. I overlooked this simple thing. Should I remove my question since I feel its a really irrelevant and silly one !!

Comment: @RmK who knows people might have this problem and find this thread, happened to me. ahahah

Comment: My `ArrayList` is empty but the `getView` is still called by `getItem` in the Viewpager adapter... Why?